# Stopwatch.ElapsedMillisecond Explanation

Tags: c#, .net, stopwatch

I need help with how this works. Microsoft's site doesn't have an answer so I was hoping there is a way to deal with this.

What would

```
stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds % 120000 == 0
```

mean?

It is in an if statement but I need to understand what is meant by that. Does it mean every 120 seconds (2 minutes), it will equal 0 and restart?

Comment: The % operator computes the remainder after dividing its first operand by its second. Which part is the If statement? :/

Comment: It's comparing if the reminder of division by 120000 equals 0

Comment: Which part is unclear? this can be easily tested by entering in a value instead of the stopwatch call

Comment: I don't _even_ understand which part you didn't get it exactly. What do you mean by _restart_ exactly?

Comment: In any event, this is very _old school_.  `stopwatch.Elapsed == TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)` is infinitely more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds % 120000 == 0
```

this statement is checking condition on milisecond elapsed in stopwatch and is it completely divisible by 120000, if it is then ok else there might be some other condition also

Answer (score 4):

`1000 milliseconds = 1 second` and therefore `120 000 milliseconds = 2 minutes`

`%` ([Mod operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)), means it returns the **remainder** of `stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds` divided by `120000`.

`== 0` means you're checking for a remainder of zero.

So therefor your statement is `true` when elapsed time is *exactly* divisible by 2 minutes (i.e. **exactly 2 mins, 4 mins, 6 mins etc.**), otherwise it will return `false`

Answer (score 2):

[The Modulus Operator (%) operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) computes the remainder after dividing its first operand by its second. All numeric types have predefined remainder operators.

`stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds % 120000 == 0` means, ElapsedMilliseconds is multiplications of 120000 (which is 2 minutes). So, your if condition hits for every 2 mins.